# Need a quality USB hub that is able to power external hardware

Tags: power, usb-hub

What is the most useful USB hub that you have had experience with.

I have a Seagate FreeAgent Go that is powered by USB and I want to get a USB hub that is able to provide me with more USB ports and can power my harddrive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the one I ended up getting

http://amzn.com/B000TTTJ36

[image: Belkin USB Hub]

Answer (score 4):

USB hubs are so generic these days.  It doesn't really matter much which ones you get from my experience.

Just make sure that it gets power from an external source (wall plug).

Answer (score 1):

What makes a quality USB Hub to power external hardware? Based on my internet research it is:

1. A quality enclosure preferably made of metal for durability;
2. Quality parts that can stand up to frequent insertions and pull outs of USB plugs;
3. Powered by an external transformer that can provide the current (amps) required for the equipment you want to attach to each USB port (e.g., for 4 standard USB ports you could potentially need 4 X 0.5 amps = 2.0 amps);
4. Sufficient power to support current requirements for the quantity of ports that you plan to use simultaneously
5. A lifetime guarantee for the product.

[Here is a link](http://www.vaunix.com/products/high-quality-usb-hub/overview.cfm) to one quality USB hub that can satisfy some of the requirements.