# Can I power a nexus 7 through a powered USB hub?

Tags: usb, power-supply, usb-hub, nexus-7

I am building a setup to use my Google Nexus 7 as a SNES. I have the games figured out, and my plan is to plug a USB hub into my OTG cable which is plugged into the device. In the hub, there are two controllers, both work on the Nexus, but the tablet trying to run the emulator and power two controllers is sucking the battery, fast.

Is there a way to have my tablet plugged in through the USB hub, the charging port being occupied, or will I have to get my hands on some way to distribute the power? If so, what can I do in that respect?

Comment: It would depend on three things, whether the main USB port allows current to pass, whether the USB Hub allows current to pass and charge your devices and, most importantly, whether the USB could supply enough current to keep it all together. You may run into a case whether the devices just keep sucking too much power.

Comment: Check this post [Can I charge USB devices from a powered hub that isn't connected to a PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/96563/can-i-charge-usb-devices-from-a-powered-hub-that-isnt-connected-to-a-pc)