# Can a USB charging port support a HUB for additonal charging?

Tags: usb, charging

Useful and helpful info regarding USB charging. I googled my question and found this site but did not see an answer for my specific question.  Here goes....

I have a power strip (surge suppressor) for all my peripherals it also has a USB charging port. If I put a standard USB hub (2 or 4 port) into the charging port with that safely give me additional charging ports? 
Thanks in advance -

GerryMS

Comment: Related [Can I charge USB devices from a powered hub that isn't connected to a PC?](http://superuser.com/q/96563)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it’ll give you more ports, but no, it’ll still provide the same amount of power. That’s of course unless the hub has a separate power supply.

So you’ll either overload the port when connecting too many devices or they may either charge very slowly or stop charging completely.